# how are featureReference nodes in Package manifest related to featureIds

Tags: solution-package, features

Our team is working on a solution with Sharepoint package having several features referenced in it.
We noted that no new updates made to the solution (i.e. features added etc.) were reflecting upon deployments. Saw the package manifest showed an error "Object reference not set to the instance ..." 
There are several

```
<featureReference itemId="<some GUID>"/>
```

entries witin the package.package manifest XML, the itemIds of these featureReference nodes do not match any of the featureIds. 
Is there a way to understand which feature is being referenced by the specific featureReference node?

Cheers,
-HK